# AccessViolationException was unhandled, calling VC dll from vb net to start an instance of NI diadem

Tags: .net, dll

I was trying to Start a diadem instance using a VC dll from my vb .net code. I'm getting the following error.

```
**System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message="Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
  Source="SDAS"
  StackTrace:
      at SDAS.SDAS.Program.InvokeDIAdemUsingDLL(String sParamTestNo) in C:\Projects\SDAS\Program.vb:line 588    
      at SDAS.SDAS.Program.MonitorPath() in C:\Projects\SDAS\Program.vb:line 267
      at SDAS.SDAS.Program.Main() in C:\Projects\SDAS\Program.vb:line 125
      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:**
```

Also, to add this code was working fine in Windows XP. Now my OS has upgraded to WIndows 7. .net development is being done with VS2008.

I'm running the application as Administrator. 
Kindly help me to sort this .

With regards
Snake

Answer (score 0):

Install the VC++ runtime.

Comment: HI ,
Thank you for the answer. It was there in my machine. i reinstalled the runtime still i'm getting the same error. Let me know if you know some way to sirt this out